# Automated test execution custom pdf reporting tool

Tags: test-automation-framework, documentation

I am automating desktop-based application testing. My requirement is that based on my execution for a particular test, I would like to mark real-time results in pdf generated by the automation script.

There is a plethora of tools (licensed/freeware) for automating desktop-based apps but could not find anything that can mark real-time results (pass/fail) in pdf generated by the automation script.

Any pointer would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when looking for desktop automation my google results show for example [9 Open Source Test Automation Tools for Desktop Applications](https://blog.testproject.io/2016/12/22/open-source-test-automation-tools-for-desktop-applications/) and [Ranorex Desktop Application Testing](https://www.ranorex.com/windows-desktop-test-automation/).

All test frameworks have to give you a test result in some form. In many cases  these will be text based and hopefully based on some standard xml, json or csv. From these results you can create PDFs, even if your framework framework does not support this feature directly. When you decided on a framework, search google for e.g. "csv to pdf" or whatever format your framework uses and then create the pdf right after your tests have run.